# NLog Not Writing

Tags: nlog

I have added NLog to my project and in the development environment, it works fine.

I created a Setup file to deploy my application. The NLog.config file did not show up as a dependency in the Setup project. So, I added it as a file and it is present in the same directory as the exe file and App.config when deployed.

It does not do any logging. I don't know why. Here is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <variable name="day" value="${date:format=dd}" />
  <variable name="month" value="${date:format=MM}" />
  <variable name="year" value="${date:format=yyyy}" />  
  <variable name="verbose" value="${longdate} | ${level} | ${message} | ${exception:format=tostring,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}}" />

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${year}${month}${day}.log" layout="${verbose}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Any help would be great. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your NLog configuration within the `yourapp.exe.config` file. Like so:

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
   </configSections>
   <nlog>
      <variable name="day" value="${date:format=dd}" />
      ...
      <targets>
         <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" .../>
      </targets>
      <rules>
         <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile" />
     </rules>
   </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Comment: the xsi tag chucks an error. how do I get the schema in there as well?

Comment: Paste in your own config, xmlns attributes and all. I removed some stuff above for readability (hence the dots). Also; see e.g. http://snipplr.com/view/24560/ and http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_support

Comment: That stuff looks good. I'll get onto that and see how it goes.

Comment: putting it in app.config w orked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Does NLog.config have the property "Copy to Output Directory" set as "Copy always"? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881521/438760

Comment: Yes. I made sure I set it to "Copy Always".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the double xml version statements (line 1 and 2) was a copy / paste issue....

Probably a dumb question, but you have the minLevel set to Error.  Are you actually encountering errors that would be logged, or have you tried lowering this to info or debug?

Comment: it was a paste error and I am deliberately throwing an exception which gets logged fine in dev conditions (IDE).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason my NLog stopped logging was different to the above suggestions.

During updating the packages, something must have automatically added an nlog section to the bottom of my Web.config. It may have been ApplicationInsights. Obviously this took preference and, this caused it to stop checking my Nlog.config file.

Once I removed the  section from my web.config it started magically reading from my nlog.config file again. I took care to take the extentions, targets and rules from web.config and ensure they were placed neatly in my nlog.config file instead.