# NLog file not writing

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I've been trying to build an app that will use NLog to log a file. The code is really basic, but not seeming to work. Anyone have any ideas? I've set the correct things to "copy always" as well, like in this question. [NLog doen't work on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850160/nlog-doent-work-on-iis/8881521#8881521)

Code below.

MAIN (Including using statements to show I am actually using them)

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using NLog;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        logger.Debug("xxxx");
    }
```

NLog.Config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<targets>
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
    layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}"
    fileName="${basedir}/log/logfile.txt" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

App.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration> 
  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c"   culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.1.0" newVersion="3.2.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Does the log folder exist? Use the `createDirs="true"` to automatically create directories for file targets. If that doesn't work you probably don't have permission to the directory.

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting here:https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting

Comment: Does your exe have write access to ${basedir} ?

Comment: the log does exist, but I will add the createDirs too. @mikez

Thanks for the link. Will check @rlee?

Comment: Good question @mihaicaracostea Do you know how to check? I assumed it would by default.

Comment: @AustinDonley Try to create an empty file from inside your code. Tip: if your application is running from a special folder (windows, program files, etc.) and is not running elevated, it will not have write permissions there by default.

Comment: It was simply a write access issue, if you're still around @mihaicaracostea, post an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks everybody for the information. I learned a lot about Nlog during this struggle.

Comment: Great to hear you've solved it! Will post in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your process has write access to the `${basedir}` location. Also, if your application is running from a special folder, make sure the process is running elevated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting a valid logger back from the GetCurrentClassLogger call?

Have you tried turning on Internal Debugging as shown here:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

This should point you in the correct direction as to why your log files are not being created

Comment: Not the problem, but it is nice information to have anyways. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to debug from Visual studio, try to run VS in elevated account ( run as administrator ) and then start debugging. This way NLog will have enough permissions to create log file.

Also use createDirs=true for each target section in nlog config file to automatically create missing folders in the log file path that is provided in the target section.