# NLog not displaying anything?

Tags: c#, nlog

for some weird reason nlog is not displaying anything when I write to the console, in the Main() method in Program.cs I assign  the nlog.config:

```
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("assets/packages/nlog/nlog.config");
```

Here is the Config:

```xml
<nlog throwExceptions="true">
  <targets>
    <target name="file" type="File" fileName="${basedir}/assets/logging/log.txt" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="File" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Here is a sample class:

```
private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public MyClass()
{
    Console.Write("lol");
    Logger.Debug("Debug test...");
    Logger.Error("Debug test...");
    Logger.Fatal("Debug test...");
    Logger.Info("Debug test...");
    Logger.Trace("Debug test...");
    Logger.Warn("Debug test...");
}
```

I know the method is being called because I get "lol", just not the actual log on the console, but it does write to /assets/logging/log.txt file.

Comment: DId you confirm that your filename path is correct?

Comment: Yes, it would throw an exception if it wasn't.

Comment: Please check the https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Answer (score 8):

In order to see the log output on the console you have to:

- Have [a configuration file](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file) (Ex: `NLog.config`)
- Ensure that [the configuration file is copied to the output directory on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785369)
- Edit it to add a target and a rule for it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets>
        <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

By creating a simple Logger class your example worked for me (using the above  config file)

```
class MyLoggerClass
{
    public static Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
}

class MyClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("lol");
        MyLoggerClass.Logger.Debug("Debug test...");
        MyLoggerClass.Logger.Error("Debug test...");
        MyLoggerClass.Logger.Fatal("Debug test...");
        MyLoggerClass.Logger.Info("Debug test...");
        MyLoggerClass.Logger.Trace("Debug test...");
        MyLoggerClass.Logger.Warn("Debug test...");
    }
}
```

Or you could use the Logger directly in your class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("lol");
        Logger.Debug("Debug test...");
        Logger.Error("Debug test...");
        Logger.Fatal("Debug test...");
        Logger.Info("Debug test...");
        Logger.Trace("Debug test...");
        Logger.Warn("Debug test...");
    }
}
```

Output from log.txt:

```
2017-02-26 16:13:44.8388|ERROR|NLogTest.Program|Debug test...
2017-02-26 16:13:44.8856|FATAL|NLogTest.Program|Debug test...
2017-02-26 16:13:44.8856|INFO|NLogTest.Program|Debug test...
2017-02-26 16:13:44.8971|WARN|NLogTest.Program|Debug test...
```

Comment: I still get nada.

Comment: Also, make sure the NLog.config is copied to the build output directory.

Comment: @ed22, U are life saver. I can't figure out why this log is not show. Coz I am not copy to output directory.Ha ha thank man.

Answer (score 2):

The basedir is relative to the .exe

In this case it would likely be in bin\debug\assets\logging\log.txt

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the data to Console as well.
Add another target that sends to console as written here:
[Nlog Console target git hub example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Console-target).

And I think you should also put that target in the `rules` → `logger` (In `writeTo` along with `File`)

Answer (score 1):

If this is still a problem for you please check this out, I copied and pasted all the necessary code and config but didnt work out until I did this one

[NLog doen't work on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850160/nlog-doent-work-on-iis/8881521#8881521)

"Copy to Output Directory" set as "Copy always"